# Let user add custom layout in reusable view

Tags: java, android

In AOSP, I want to add a custom view to add a checkbox that can be checked to hide and show the content that is passed in the body of my CheckableView.

How to make it so my xml tag is rendered and hidden/shown when the checkbox is clicked

```xml
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logger_output"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_cb"/>
```

```xml
-- activity_main.xml
<com.example.view.CheckableView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:checkboxText="@string/cbText">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logger_output"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_cb"/>
</com.example.view.CheckableView>
```

that declaration would only add a checkbox that hides and shows the body content of `com.example.view.CheckableView`